# Heroku H18 error in a Rails app on an unhandled route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I'm getting mysterious H18 errors on Heroku. Theses requests seems to be made by bots or crawlers sending POST requests on the root URL of my application. What concerns me is that these requests all take more than 30 seconds to process before they get terminated, most likely by a timeout. Here is a sample of my log file and Metric graph:

```
Dec 14 03:52:26 poll-en heroku/router sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/" host=app.do request_id=72252a6a-d4b5-4ecc-ae3c-bc69c273eb16 fwd="138.201.76.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30034ms status=503 bytes=71 protocol=http
Dec 14 04:05:11 poll-en heroku/router sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/" host=app.do request_id=78ea5ae4-9e8a-4c90-b26e-c2eae40116b4 fwd="148.251.231.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31392ms status=503 bytes=71 protocol=http
Dec 14 04:19:07 poll-en heroku/router sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/" host=app.do request_id=bcc76545-24e0-4fc7-8e63-a08bb463bb31 fwd="148.251.231.105" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30195ms status=503 bytes=71 protocol=http
Dec 14 04:45:35 poll-en heroku/router sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/" host=app.do request_id=87efe086-9879-4506-a7ac-52504219126d fwd="144.76.141.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31733ms status=503 bytes=71 protocol=http
```

[image]

My application doesn't handle POST requests on the root URL and I can't replicate the error using cURL. Just to be sure, I also added a Rack Middleware that runs first and terminates all POST requests on the root URL. So the request shouldn't even reach the Rails router but I still get these H18 errors in my log file.

How can this happen? What kind of request could hang for 30 seconds when it is not even reaching my app?

Comment: Does your app allow `http` requests or is it `https` only?  I have seen requests take a long time to timeout when it requests `http` but the app only uses `https` and there is some hangup with the redirecting.

Comment: I set `config.force_ssl = true` so `http` requests are redirected to `https`. I'm also testing this http requests with cURL and it returns instantly. This is a real puzzle!

Comment: @RockwellRice I think you might be on to something. Were you able to change a config to fix this?

Comment: No, in our case it was a DNS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Puma are you using and what does your Puma config look like?

[Heroku documents](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h18-server-request-interrupted) that the request do reach your app when H18 happens:

> An H18 signifies that the socket connected, some data was sent as part of a response by the app, but then the socket was destroyed without completing the response.

Perhaps you are experiencing this bug in Puma, where is sounds like the request can be stuck in Puma (never reaching your app): https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2282 (solved in Puma 5.0.3 and above)

You could try setting [`first_data_timeout`](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v5.1.1/lib/puma/dsl.rb#L263-L267) in your Puma config to something that's lower than 30 seconds. Then Puma should [respond with 408 Request Timeout](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v5.1.1/test/test_puma_server.rb#L384-L393) before Heroku gives you the H18 error.

Comment: My app is running on the latest version of Puma (5.1.1). I will try adding the `first_data_timeout` config and see if it helps. I will report back. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the `first_data_timeout` to 10 seconds did indeed reduce the H18 timeout to 10 seconds. I still don't know how to get rid of these errors but at least it doesn't hang the server response for as long. Do you know how aggressive I can go with this setting? Could I set it to 1 second since I don't see any scenario where a client would open a socket without sending data (not using websockets in my app).

Comment: Are you still seeing H18 errors in your logs with the lower `first_data_timeout`? That doesn't sound right to me. It could be a bug in Puma. You are welcome to open an issue at https://github.com/puma/puma with more information (logs, more info about your app and the clients that are likely to connect to it).

Comment: Yes, the H18 error still occur in my logs and on the metrics graph, only they happen after the number of seconds set in the `first_data_timeout` is reached. I don't see why this would be a bug, I am pleased with the fact that I can lower this threshold but still be warned about the errors.

Comment: If I understand the `first_data_timeout` option in Puma correctly, it shouldn't trigger any H18. Puma should respond with HTTP status 408 and it should be a complete response. That's why I thought it could be a bug in Puma. Are the H18 warnings useful to you somehow?

Comment: Ok I opened a bug report here: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2539